# Getting KeyError : 3

Tags: python, graph, depth-first-search, topological-sort

Getting KeyError: 3 when trying to do the following to find the topological sort:

```
def dfs_topsort(graph):         # recursive dfs with 
    L = []                      # additional list for order of nodes
    color = { u : "white" for u in graph }
    found_cycle = [False]
    for u in graph:
        if color[u] == "white":
            dfs_visited(graph, u, color, L, found_cycle)
        if found_cycle[0]:
            break

    if found_cycle[0]:           # if there is a cycle, 
        L = []                   # then return an empty list  

    L.reverse()                  # reverse the list
    return L                     # L contains the topological sort


def dfs_visited(graph, u, color, L, found_cycle):
    if found_cycle[0]:
        return
    color[u] = "gray"
    for v in graph[u]:
        if color[v] == "gray":
            found_cycle[0] = True
            return
        if color[v] == "white":
            dfs_visited(graph, v, color, L, found_cycle)
    color[u] = "black"      # when we're done with u,
    L.append(u)

graph_tasks = {1: [2,11],
    2: [3],
    11: [12],
    12: [13]
    }
order = dfs_topsort(graph_tasks)

for task in order:
    print(task)
```

I'm getting KeyError: 3 for the above example. Why is that so? How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `dfs_topsort` algorithm needs a `key` for every `value` that exists in the graph.

So we need to include keys for each of the values. The first one that's missing is `3`, which caused the `KeyError: 3`, and also `13`. If we include these keys and give them empty values (because they are not connected to any other nodes) then it fixes the error.

Also, the other example you gave in the comment works because every value (right-hand side) ( `[2,3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 6], [5, 6], [6], []` ) is also in the Key values (left-hand side) [`1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`].

So using `graph_tasks = { 1: [2, 11], 2: [3], 3: [], 11: [12], 12: [13], 13: [] }` gives the output you may be expecting.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: But when I do as you suggest, dfs_topsort returns null. What I'm doing is working for other examples, but not this one. How to fix this??

Comment: I think you need to change the same logic in `dfs_topsort` function: change `for u in graph:` to `for u in graph.iterkeys():`. Also, it returns `None` not `null`, and according to your code comments, "if there is a cycle, then return an empty list", so shouldn't this be True, and it returns `None`?

Comment: No, if I use this example: graph = {
        1: [2, 3],
        2: [4, 5, 6],
        3: [4,6],
        4: [5,6],
        5: [6],
        6: []
    }, what I was doing gives the correct output. Even after changing it to graph.iterkey() in dfs_topsort, it returns nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about the problems you are trying to solve, I thought you just wanted to fix the KeyError..

Comment: It looks like you are searching a graph of Integers and looking for a matching String? Which of course won't work. Are you trying to modify [this code tutorial](https://algocoding.wordpress.com/2015/04/05/topological-sorting-python/) to work with lists of integers?

Comment: @Angad, I think I figured out the problem you were having with getting KeyError: 3 for those `graph` values. The `dfs_topsort` algorithm needs a Key for every value that exists in the graph. So the other example you gave in the comment works because every value (right-hand side) ( [2,3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 6], [5, 6], [6], [] ) is also in the Key values (left-hand side) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. So the way to fix the graph values you used in the question, you need to include Keys for each of the values. The first one that's missing is `3`, which caused the error, and also `13`.

Comment: So using `graph_tasks = { 1: [2, 11], 2: [3], 3: [], 11: [12], 12: [13], 13: [] }` gives the output you may be expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as yours and I found out that it's not searching the value of 3 from my dataset. What I did is to add a list for my 3 values. You might want to add something like:

```
graph_tasks = {...,
...,
3: [n,n],
...,
...,
}
```